# The entity type 'MigrationOperation' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to build my first .NET app using Identity.  It will be a basic Workout app, but I have been having trouble figuring out the Keys and ForeignKeys within Identity.  Here is my ExerciseController:

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
 using WorkoutGenerator.Data.Migrations;

    namespace RandomWorkout.Models
    {
    public class Exercise
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public MuscleGroup MuscleGroup { get; set; }
        public int MuscleGroupID { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ID")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        public IList<ExerciseWorkout> ExerciseWorkouts { get; set; } = new List<ExerciseWorkout>();
    }

}`
```

When I run the migration however, I get the error

> They entity type 'MigrationOperation' requires a primary key to be
>   defined.

I have run into this issue with other entities, in which case I just had to make a new builder.Entity in my DbContext class.  With the MigrationOperation however, this doesn't seem to be the case.  Am I completely on the wrong track of how to JOIN my table with the auto generated User table? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `"Id"` instead of `"ID"`?

Comment: @Marathon55 Just did.  Same result unfortunately.  I feel like joining my table to the AspNetUsers table is super simple and I'm just not seeing it

Comment: Would this be a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: @Marathon55 this one would be, yes.  I will also be implementing a one to many to another of my tables (workouts).  Should I have an intermediary take like I do for my own tables?(Its a ExerciseWorkout table). I've done both relationships on my own, I'm just not sure how to work it in with this Identity library

Comment: For a many-to-many relationship, I recommend an intermediary table.

Comment: `namespace RandomWorkout.Models
{
    public class ExerciseWorkout
    {
        public int WorkoutID { get; set; }
        public Workout Workout { get; set; }

        public int ExerciseID { get; set; }
        public Exercise Exercise { get; set; }
    }
}`  I have this as an intermediary table in my own custom tables, are you saying I should have something like this, but replace workout with ApplicationUser?

Comment: Yeah, that's right

Comment: I had this exact problem crop up today, and the reason was that the ef core migration was generated with the same name as the new entity - it did a weird partial class thing, and suddenly MigrationOperation was being treated as an entity (or something).

Check the migration name, and if it's just an entity name, change it to be descriptive. (for example, change the name "Author" to "AddAuthorTable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> ```
> public class Exercise {
>     public string Name { get; set; } 
>     public string Description { get; set; } 
>     public MuscleGroup MuscleGroup { get; set; }
>     public int MuscleGroupID { get; set; } 
>
>     [Key] 
>     public int Id { get; set; } 
>
>     public int UserId {get; set;}
>     [ForeignKey("UserId")] 
>     public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; } 
>
>     public IList<ExerciseWorkout> ExerciseWorkouts { get; set; } = new List<ExerciseWorkout>(); 
>  }
> ```

Add a int for foreignkey and define an id property for primary key

Comment: I am getting the same response of MigrationOperation Entity needs a primary key.  Three questions that might narrow it down.  1.  Do I need to add a .Entity<>()HasKey.() in my DbContext.cs like I did for my personal many-to-many relationship?  2.  Do I need to add any code to the ApplicationUser.cs file?  3.  Is Add-Migration not the correct command in the package console (and do I need to remove all data from my databases?)

Comment: So, i think the problem ist in entity excercise

Comment: Please , can you post your model?

Comment: Oh?  Do you have any idea what it might be?  Should I be douing something in the ApplicationUser entity?  It is completely empty as of now, I wasn't sure if anything should be in it.

Comment: for this, i need review your model

Comment: It might just be easier for me to send you to my github https://github.com/bdburns6389/WorkoutGenerator.  It is under the testing branch.  If you don't want to look at that, I can post specifics later today(I just got to work)

Comment: Ok, i check this when i arrived to my Office.

Comment: Thank you.  It is much appreciated

Comment: @BrianBurns you have data on Database? you have some errors on your model, first, the Id of ApplicationUser as string, not integer, then, on excersice model , you need a using WorkoutGenerator.Models, for the rest models, you need add Key attribute on ID property

Comment: @BrianBurns I already corrected the errors in the repository clone, now it works fine on my pc, but I can not confirm changes because I'm not a contributor. How do you like the changes?

Comment: When you say the id of ApplicationUser as a string, are your referring to inside my Exercise.cs file?  If so, right now I have it as virtual, not string...

Comment: @BrianBurns yes, but you have  **public int UserId {get; set;}** change this to **public string UserId{get;set;}**

Comment: Oh, ok, gotcha.  When I do that however, i get a 'ApplicationUser is an ambiguous reference between 'WorkoutGenerator.Data.Migrations.ApplicationUser and WorkoutGenerator.Models.ApplicationUser.

Comment: remove this **using WorkoutGenerator.Data.Migrations;**

Comment: Ok, That is working so far. Unfortunately I have to get back to work.  I will comment back when I am able to delete my database and redo the migrations.  Is there a single command that does that?  Ive always just manually deleted the database and rerun the InitialCreate migration

Comment: happy code, if your help served you, please mark as a valid answer

Comment: Thank you.  I marked you as the answer, hopefully I can get it to work from here

Answer (score 0):

for solved this problem It's better define id private the get by your Id

```
private Guid _id;
[Key]
public Guid ID
{
get { return _id; }
}
```