# The entity type 'MigrationOperation' requires a primary key to be defined, but MigrationOperation is part of EF Core and [Key]s are defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49123379/the-entity-type-migrationoperation-requires-a-primary-key-to-be-defined), I have an entity that is not behaving with the same (or similar) error:

```cs
// User.cs
public class User {
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public string? DisplayName { get; set; }
    // Populated via .Include()
    public virtual ICollection<GroupMembership> Memberships { get; set; }
}

// GroupMembership.cs
public class GroupMembership {
    // Can also be compound key <UserId, GroupId>, but it is singular for troubleshooting.
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid GroupId { get; set; }
}
```

> They entity type 'MigrationOperation' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'

However, all my classes have a primary `[Key]` already defined, and no: I don't have any tables, types, members or references called `MigrationOperation`.

And I'm confident that [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.operations.migrationoperation?view=efcore-7.0) is `MigrationOperation`.

I've tried:

- Making sure all models have a `[Key]` (solution in the above question)
- Resetting the database and re-applying every migration from the start
- `modelBuilder.Entity<MigrationOperation>().HasNoKey()`, which results in a startup error for the obvious reason of `MigrationOperation` not being a valid model, and not really a solution/attempt either.
- Removing all foreign key or compound key constraints that isn't primary key and applying that to the database (still the same error come up)

I read somewhere there was some sort of "common sense" key detection. Should I be disabling that, and if so, how?

---

Update: Manage to get a full call stack:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'MigrationOperation' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.'

    [async function]
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync.__Logged|12_1(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker invoker)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync() Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync() Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync() Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()   Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync.__Logged|17_1(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker invoker)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync() Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.MvcAttributeRouteHandler.RouteAsync.AnonymousMethod__0(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext c)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
    Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll!Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext) Unknown
    Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll!Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.UseMiddleware.AnonymousMethod__2(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.DefaultFilesMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    ReadiSkills.Web.dll!ReadiSkills.Web.Infrastructure.SpaRouteHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Line 19  C#
    NetEscapades.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders.dll!NetEscapades.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders.SecurityHeadersMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Line 68 C#
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite.RewriteMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)   Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HstsMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.dll!Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.ExecuteWithFilterAsync(Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.IHttpSocketAdapter injectScriptSocket, string requestId, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext)   Unknown
    Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.dll!Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.InvokeAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.dll!Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.VsContentMiddleware.InvokeAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.BrowserRefreshMiddleware.InvokeAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.ProcessRequestAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context context)   Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context>.ProcessRequestAsync()   Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.HandleRequest() Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.Execute()   Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()  Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart() Unknown
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()  Unknown
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing to generate this error? Is it a compilation error, run-time exception or something else?

Comment: Should `GroupMembership` have a navigation property of type `User` and possibly another of type `Group`?

Comment: Does one of your entity types have a `MigrationOperation` property?

Comment: @jmcilhinney This error occurs on any lookup; ie. when you call `dbContext.Users.ToListAsync()`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Nope.

Comment: EF Core model errors would be thrown on first use of any `DbContext`, `User` is unlikely to be the source of the problem. EF Core conventions will discover types based on `DbSet<T>` properties, and any other class properties that might be navigations. `MigrationOperation` would also be discovered from any `Migration` class. You'll have to inspect (or grep?) *every* entity type on your context looking for any weird properties that aren't `[NotMapped]`.

Comment: Did you create a migration, with the same name as one of your entity types? Do you have a `using ...` that could cause this migration type to be referenced as a navigation property, instead of the type you expect?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I doubt it because there's no references to that in my app's code or comments; all search results are for references within EF-related packages. As for migrations with the same name as another type: also no.

Comment: The [`MigrationOperation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.operations.migrationoperation) class is the base for all EF migration operations, e.g. if you add a column then the migration calls `AddColumn` and that creates an instance of the derived `AddColumnOperation` class. That seems to be what it's referring to but I'm not really sure why. Are you seeing similar behaviour in other projects that also use EF Core?

Comment: Do you get a stack trace with the exception? If so, please add it to the question.

Comment: It doesn't but I'll try to fish for one

Comment: I'm not having any luck getting one; they all end at the `DbSet<T>`

Comment: Add some code to the end of your `OnModelCreating`. Loop through all `modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()`, list any unexpected `entity.ClrType`, then search your entity types for those type names.